# Selecting files to tar with specifized size limit

Tags: email, unix, zip, tar

i have a requirement, where i have a directory with 1.csv,2.csv,3.csv...

I'm using tar to archive the file

tar -cvf file1.tar" *.csv

and using gzip to zip the files

gzip file.tar

Now the problem what i have is since the size of the zipped tar file is more than 25MB and there is restriction of the attachment size.. i cannot mail it as an attachment to the email

So im looking for a sh file which will tar.gz files to the size of 25 mb and if it's more than 25mb create an other tar.gz file with rest of file and so on..

i don't want to split and unsplit the tar. is there anything which can be done on this?

Comment: Splitting sounds the simplest solution, why don't you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the zip -s option to compress your tar file into 25mb files.

```
zip -s 25m my_archive.zip my_archive.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try bzip2 compression instead of gzip. It is a slower, but generally more efficient compression algorithm.

Command line would become:

```
tar -cvjf file1.tar.bz2 *.csv
```

You would then extract with the following command:

```
tar -xjvf file1.tar.bz2
```

Hard to tell if it will be enough to get under 25 MB, though.

Answer (score -1):

Ascertain what compression factor you're getting from gzip.

Tar only enough of your CSV files to produce a zipped archive smaller than 25MB

Repeat as necessary.